# Change a web service URL at runtime

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I am developing an application that will connect to various Web services according to the user's location .

For example :

If the user are in the city "A", the application will connect to the Web service: "192.168.1.1:8010", if he goes to the city "B", will connect to "192.168.1.1:8020", in the city "C" will be "192.168.1.1:8030" , and so on.

The IP address is always the same , what changes is the port number.

Simple thing huh? Yeah, but I can't find a way to make it work at runtime!

When I change the " URL" parameter(myWS.Url) of the Web service("URL Behaivor == Dynamic") at runtime, the server only returns null , changing the parameter to it's original value, the communication is restored .

Same thing if the change is made before compilation, compile to the city "A" , works only in the city "A" , compile to the city "B" , works only in the city "B".

The application is originally developed for Windows CE 5.0 using VS2008 and CF3.5, but even in VS2013 with . NET Framework 4.0 and Windows Seven the "problem" still happens.

Has anyone experienced this?

As requested, here is a small part of my code:

```
WSR.WSR myWS = new WSR.WSR();

//WSR added as a Web Reference

if (City_A)
{
    myWS.Url = "http://192.168.1.1:8010/WSR.apw";
}
else
{
    myWS.Url = "http://192.168.1.1:8020/WSR.apw";
}
```

The solution purposed in this topic([What should be modified to change the URL of a web service in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810967/what-should-be-modified-to-change-the-url-of-a-web-service-in-c)) doesn't work for me because, as I said, when I changed the "URL Behavior" property no entry point was created in my app.config file.

Here is the app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="TrocaWebService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 

    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/></startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings />
        <client />
    </system.serviceModel>
    <userSettings>
        <TrocaWebService.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="TrocaWebService_WSR_WSR" serializeAs="String">
                <value>http://192.168.1.1:8010/WSR.apw</value>
            </setting>
        </TrocaWebService.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you trying to redirect a user that hits port 80 to a different port based on something?

Comment: Is the Ports dynamic?

Comment: Do you have some code that you can show that might help find the problem.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: I gave up to make this thing work this way and I changed the webservices code to join all in one, passing the cities as a parameter. It is not best practice, but it works. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

I am using WCF binding (Visual Studio -> Add Service Reference) to create proxy classes against a WSDL.  Then at run time I'll create a `ClientBase` (which has an endpoint (ie url)) using this code:

```
public static class ServiceClientFactory
{
    public static HttpBindingBase BuildBinding(string endpointUrl)
    {
        if (endpointUrl.ToLower().StartsWith("https"))
        {
            var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport);
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue - 1;
            return binding;
        }

        else
        {
            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue - 1;
            return binding;
        }
    }

    public static TClient CreateClient<TClient, TChannel>(string endpoint, string username, string password)
        where TClient : ClientBase<TChannel>
        where TChannel : class
    {
        var client = (TClient)
            Activator.CreateInstance(
                typeof (TClient),
                BuildBinding(endpoint),
                new EndpointAddress(endpoint));

        if (null == client.ClientCredentials)
            throw new Exception(
                string.Format("Error initializing [{0}] client.  Client Credentials object was null",
                    typeof(TClient).Name));


       //This is for setting Basic Auth
       client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential =
            new NetworkCredential(
                username,
                password);

        client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel =
            TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation;

       return client;
    }
}
```

}